# Замена в строке двойного пробела на одинарный

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть строка:

```
str = 'A l a  m a  k o t a'
```

Как видно в строке, между буквами одного слова у меня один пробел, между словами  два.
Хочу преобразовать строку в :

```
'Ala ma kota'
```

Пытался решить так, но потерпел крах:

Cначала меняю двойные пробелы на '``':

```
for i in range(len(str)-1):
    if str[i] == ' ' and str[i+1]== ' ':
        comment.replace('str[i]', '`')
        comment.replace('str[i + 1]', '`')
```

Потом удаляю одинарные:

```
str.replace(' ', '')
```

И в конце заменяю '``' на пробел:

```
str.replace('``',' ')
```

Но вся эта конструкция не работает. Как можно решить данную задачу?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не называйте переменные именами встроенных типов!

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями, заменив первый пробел ни на что и сохранив второй

```
import re

regex = r"\s(\s)?"
test_str = "'A l a  m a  k o t a'"
subst = "\\1"

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)) # 'Ala ma kota'
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/I6ZJhq/2)

---

а вот так можно заменить любое кол-во пробелов, больше одного, на один пробел

```
regex = r"\s((\s)(\s+)?)?"
subst = "\\2"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/I6ZJhq/3)

Answer (score 8):

Вариант без использования регулярных выражений:

```
s = "A l a  m a  k o t a"
res = s.replace("  ", "~!~").replace(" ", "").replace("~!~", " ")
print(res)
# Ala ma kota
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать встроенный метод `join()`

```
string = 'A l a  m a  k o t a'
f = string.split('  ')
print(' '.join([''.join(res.split()) for res in f])
```

Answer (score 3):

Если задача учебная, то можно перебрать в цикле все символы, копируя их в новую строку и пропуская пробелы при встрече - когда попадается пробел, просто переходим к следующему символу, не записывая этот пробел в новую строку. Таким образом одиночные пробелы игнорируются, "вторые" пробелы попадают в результат.

```
string = 'A l a  m a  k o t a'
new_string = ''

itr = iter(string)
try:
    while True:
        char = next(itr)
        if char == ' ':
            char = next(itr)

        new_string += char
except StopIteration:
    print(new_string)
```

**Output**

```
Ala ma kota
```